# OSGI LogService.log method does not work!

Tags: osgi, equinox, apache-felix

I have the weirdest bug, when writting my LogHelper class.

I am using **org.osgi.service.log.LogService** (with Apache Felix implementation).

Now I can call the:

```
LogService.log(int level, String message)
```

with no problems, but when I try to use the one with the exception:

```
LogService.log(int level, String message, Throwable exception)
```

Eclipse highlights the call as wrong, and gives me this wierd error message:

> The type org.osgi.framework.ServiceReference cannot be resolved. 
>   It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to nice folks at [apache felix](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FELIX-2826?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=12991732#comment-12991732) this is because Eclipse does not see ServiceReference in my classpath.

Putting the "org.osgi.core" into my (maven+osgi) dependencies, fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Your bundle should import package **org.osgi.framework** that is used by **LogService**.

Comment: Hm... I think I pointed out that I CAN call log(int level, String message) method, but I cannot call the method with a Throwable in it's signature.